# Can I replace table with a view (of same name).?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, view

I have 2 databases....a & b

I have table "t" in both of these databases.

Now I am deleting table t from database "b".

I create a view "t" (see that name of view is same as deleted table) in
   database "b"...and this view referring the table "t" in database "a".

I have a dotnet application..which point to database "b". It has inline queries....
   So can I leave the reference like this "b.t" in inline queries.
   I mean now will it refer view "t" instead of table "t" ?

Comment: Be careful about foreign keys and make sure that stored procedures and other elements can work with a view instead of a table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, but the table you're looking to replace has to either be dropped or renamed first -- only one object can have the name.

Use:

```
CREATE VIEW b.dbo.t AS
  SELECT a.*
    FROM a.dbo.t a
```

The only caveat is users in the B datbase might need to be granted SELECT privilege:

```
GRANT SELECT ON b.dbo.t TO user
```

Ideally, create a role, then grant SELECT to the role which you can then include add to users.

Comment: My question is not how to create view...If I create a view with same name as deleted table. Do I have to change any references in my stored procedure/inline queries ?

Comment: @Anish: As long as column names and their data types match, things should be fine but recompiling the SP/etc can't hurt.

Comment: No, you don't have to change the references, so long as they are in the same schema nameset

Comment: @ OMG => what u meant by "but recompiling the SP/etc can't hurt. "

Comment: @Anish: In Management Studio, right click the SP, click "refresh". Etc.